# Cannot forward to error page for request ... as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, Thymeleaf, Spring Security, JDK 10, Apache Tomcat 9.0.6 . I have controller

```
package com.donhuvy.controller;

import com.donhuvy.entity.Ccy;
import com.donhuvy.repository.CcyRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ccy")
public class CcyController {

    private static final int INITIAL_PAGE = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    @Autowired
    CcyRepository ccyRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAllPaginatingCcy(
            @RequestParam("pageSize") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
            @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page) {
        int evalPageSize = pageSize.orElse(INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
        int evalPage = (page.orElse(0) < 1) ? INITIAL_PAGE : page.get() - 1;
        Page<Ccy> currencies = ccyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize));
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cash/ccy");
        modelAndView.addObject("currencies", currencies);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/vy")
    public String foo(@RequestParam("pageSize") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
                      @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, Model model){

        int evalPageSize = pageSize.orElse(INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
        int evalPage = (page.orElse(0) < 1) ? INITIAL_PAGE : page.get() - 1;
        Page<Ccy> currencies = ccyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize));

        model.addAttribute("currencies", currencies);
        return "cash/ccy";
    }

}
```

at `application.properties` I have

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

I have configuration class

```
package com.donhuvy.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Configuration for overall application.
 */
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


    /**
     * Switch language, default language is Vietnamese - Vy's mother tongue language.
     * If user would like to switch to other language, use parameter,
     * for example: http://localhost:8081/web/cash/cash_receipt?lang=en
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        // sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        Locale vietnamLocale = new Locale("vi", "VN");
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(vietnamLocale);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry ir) {
        ir.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

When I access `http://localhost:8081/cash/ccy` or `http://localhost:8081/cash/vy` I see the same error

```
/Users/donhuvy/Documents/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.6/bin/catalina.sh run
[2018-03-25 11:01:17,218] Artifact Gradle : com.donhuvy : accounting-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49344', transport: 'socket'
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.548 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.6
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 5 2018 09:34:35 UTC
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.6.0
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.13.3
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           10+46
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            "Oracle Corporation"
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/donhuvy/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/tomcat/Unnamed_accounting
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/donhuvy/Documents/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.6
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/donhuvy/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/tomcat/Unnamed_accounting/conf/logging.properties
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49344,suspend=y,server=n
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:/Users/donhuvy/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar=/private/var/folders/lj/tgdhz0mx5t54vglcc8982vbc0000gn/T/capture823.props
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:/Users/donhuvy/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --illegal-access=warn
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/donhuvy/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/tomcat/Unnamed_accounting
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/donhuvy/Documents/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.6
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/donhuvy/Documents/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.6/temp
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/donhuvy/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
25-Mar-2018 11:01:18.606 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
```

...

```
2018-03-25 11:05:14 ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/ccy/vy] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

The full console log is https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/ad3f65955292d9874805c99c03f3227f#file-console-log-L450

How to fix it?

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` remove the view resolver and default handler config from your `WebConfig`.

Comment: *response has already been committed* states that part of the the response is sent (commited) to the user but then it stuck in a **Error** that prevents it from further UI rendering.

Comment: Thank @M.Deinum Your comment help me config correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing Thymeleaf dependency. I must add this line to `build.gradle`

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.0.0.RELEASE')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable ErrorPageFilter to remove the error log by configuring in your Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
    return new ErrorPageFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);

    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

In Spring Boot by configuring with the second @Bean is enough.

Comment: For newer versions of Spring Boot it seems you also need to enable bean overriding as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723731/957731).

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was caused by a `<s:include>` in my jsp that was pointing to a file that couldn't be found.
My java console and logs were giving `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter : Cannot forward to error page for request [/my-app/my-app-sub] as the response has already been committed.` and the web browser was giving a `404`.
When I corrected the file location that I gave in the `<s:include>`, the error went away.