# Swagger with MapStruct throws org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, swagger

I'm trying to implement swagger2 in my project. (Spring Boot project)
I've followed this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Then I've included swagger into `pom.xml`:

```
<spring.boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I've created a `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now when I start up the application, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [configuration.SwaggerConfig]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'licenseMapperImpl' for bean class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.LicenseMapperImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [data.mapper.LicenseMapperImpl]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'licenseMapperImpl' for bean class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.LicenseMapperImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [data.mapper.LicenseMapperImpl]
```

`LicenseMapperImpl` is generated by MapStruct, and I dont understand how to solve this problem.
I think a possible solution should be to add name to the compoment but mapstruct, but I've found this bug on his repository 
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1427.

`ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` should be thrown with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class. 
But they shouldn't exist two bean of `LicenseMapperImpl.class` and `LicenseMapperImpl.class` is a simple component.

Here is `LicenseMapperImpl.class`:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2019-07-19T11:46:08+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.3.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class LicenseMapperImpl implements LicenseMapper {

    @Override
    public License toEntity(LicenseDto dto) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public LicenseDto toDto(License entity) {
       // do something
    }

    @Override
    public List<License> toEntity(List<LicenseDto> dtoList) {
       // do something
    }

    @Override
    public List<LicenseDto> toDto(List<License> entityList) {
      // do something
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

I've renamed `LicenseMapper` to `LicenseServiceMapper` and all work fine.
I dont undestand how, if anyone can clear my mind I would be happy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot - BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723303/springboot-beandefinitionoverrideexception-invalid-bean-definition)

Comment: @DarrenForsythe no, it is not the same, in issue you linked there are problems with bean definition overriding, here in question the problem is with the Bean that have the same name as in Swagger package and local bean, it gives ConflictingBeansDefinition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not sure why this happens but I found a simple solution for our project:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, implementationName = "test")
public interface ModelMapper {

    ModelMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ModelMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "lastUpdated", source = "time")
    Model modelDtoToEntity(ModelDto modelDto);

    @Mapping(target = "time", source = "lastUpdated")
    ModelDto entityToModelDto(Model model);

}
```

I've just added the attribute `implementationName` and gave it a custom name (here `implementationName = "test"`). I also tried renaming like you said but that did not fix it for me.

I'm using MapStruct 1.3.1.Final and Swagger 3.0.0 with Gradle

Answer (score 0):

resolved by renaming LicenseMapper to LicenseServiceMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to swagger when I moved the mapper from one package to another, I got the same error. I fixed it by running `mvn clean` , or it can be fixed by just deleting already generated `/target` dir.